# WinForms designer breaks on VS2005 when using Windows 7

Tags: winforms, windows-7, visual-studio-2005, windows-forms-designer

We have an old project that is designed using VS2005 and WinForms. Everything works perfectly on Windows XP, but when I open the designer on Windows 7, everything breaks down.

The controls get sized to random size and some of them dissappear (or are moved to random coordinates).

What can we do to solve this issue? Should we switch to VS2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we used TableLayoutPanel inside a GroupBox and not on the form. When we added the TableLayoutPanel on the form and moved the GroupBox into it, the designer stays ok.

Answer (score 0):

A newer version of VS should help, but i'd be surprised if this can't be fixed in 2005.

Try commenting everything out in the method where initializeComponent runs, or any properties that set UI change. You should find it easy enough, it's a method that has long lists of calls against the controls on the form.

Comment: But the problem is that the designers are still ok when opened in WinXP. Only in Win7 they appear to be broken. What would commenting out controls help?

Comment: I just hoped to follow a process of elimination, hopefully one of those settings is OK in XP but the Windows7 version has a problem. Eliminating all of those things in one move would help prove that.